# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource When setting property bag

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I'm using azure ad to get the share point context and also in Azure function to manage site collections.
But when I tried to setting property bag,it failed.My azure ad application have the full control of site permission.

```
Sites.FullControl.All
Application
Have full control of all site collections
Yes



using (ClientContext context = spHelper.GetAzureADOnlyClientContext(hostUrl, spAzureAppId, spTenant, certificate, false))
                {
                    tenant.SetSiteAdmin(hostUrl, siteCreationInfo.TechnicalOwnerEmail, true);
                    admClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    string description = siteCreationInfo.Description;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
                    {
                        //setting the propertyBag to flag the site created by CDA
                        context.Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["Createdby"] = "CDA-V0.5";
                        context.Site.RootWeb.Description = description;
                        context.Site.RootWeb.Update();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (context.HasPendingRequest)
                        {
                            context.ExecuteQuery();
                        }
                        logHelper.writeLog("Site updated!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logHelper.writeLog("Update site error:" + ex.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
```

Do I miss some more settings?

Comment: What error message did it show ?

Comment: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Comment: Did you refer to some document about this update site sdk ? Could you please share the link of the document ?

Comment: And may I know which document point you that you need the `Sites.FullControl.All` permission ?

Comment: I just mean that I have a azure ad application and give this permission and then use `GetAzureADOnlyClientContext`  to get context

Comment: The type is application

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that permission is "application" which mentioned in your question. You add the permission under sharepoint or microsoft graph ?

Comment: I'm using sharepoint not microsoft graph

Comment: Have you refreshed the `certificate` after you add the permission ?

Comment: yeah,I could use the context to create site and so on.But failed when I tried to set site property bag

Comment: Have you tried add the other few permissions for sites ?

Comment: I could add user to the groups and set site admin and so on.